# Can I travel to Spain with Kosovo passport?

Tags: spain

I wanted to know if I will be allowed to get into Spain with my Kosovo passport?
I have a Schengen visa but not sure if I should try to go!

Answer (score 5):

Kosovo is not recognized as a state by Spain, so if you only have a 'regular' Kosovan passport, you are not entitled to travel to Spain, even if you have a Schengen visa. Are you sure that you have a uniform Schengen visa (USV) at all, valid for all Schengen states? Since Kosovo is not recognized by Spain, other Schengen countries usually only issue Schengen visas with limited territorial validity (LTV) for all Schengen countries except Spain to Kosovan citizens.

The only travel documents recognized by Spain for inhabitans of Kosovo are travel documents issued by the United Nations Interim Administration Mission in Kosovo. You can find some more details [here](http://visados.com/en/visa-for-Spain).

Comment: Thanks for this. I deleted my own answer because I had absolutely no idea about the Kosovo thing. It was just a logical assumption.

Comment: "Kosovo is not recognized as a state by Spain, so if you only have a 'regular' Kosovan passport, you are not entitled to travel to Spain" Just because a country is not recognized as a state by another country does not mean its passport is not accepted as a valid travel document by that other country. For example, almost no countries recognize the Republic of China as a state, but almost all countries accept its passport for travel.

Comment: @user102008 Of course not, but as you can read on the page I'm linking to, Spain does not recognize Kosovan passports and that is the issue in this question.