# Travelling to Spain with a Kosovan passport, what are the outcomes if caught?

Tags: spain, kosovo-citizens

I would like to know what happens if you travel to Spain and try to enter with a Kosovan passport and police catch you? Is there a fine, if so how much, or can anything more serious happen than not allowing me to cross the border?

I will be entering Spain from France via bus, and have a Schengen visa. I need to attend a conference and I have the invitation as well, but I am concerned about the border issue as I have been told there are controls now.

Comment: It's now even more unclear what are you asking. Your problem is _not_ the spanish border, but entering France after you were in Kosovo. Once you are legally in France, you can travel to Spain.

Comment: When you applied for the visa for France, did you mention going to Spain?

Comment: @minus.273 It would seem that Spain does not recognize a Kosovo passport. So this is not a general situation that can be resolved by the general rules.

Comment: @minus.273 Yes, what I would like to know is if anyone has experience this and what happened to them when entering

Comment: @flirtymuffin I found a 1 year old statement from a Spanish Consulate in Hamburg with a definite statement that the Kosovo passport is not recognize. It would be interesting to see what is stated on your Schengen C-Visa 'Valid For' field.

Comment: Related to: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53801/can-i-travel-to-spain-with-kosovo-passport

Comment: 14 Apr 2018  https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/more-than-half-schengen-ltv-visas-obtained-by-kosovars-in-2017/    .... _However, Kosovo citizens can still enter these five countries with travel documents issued by the United Nations Interim Administration Mission in Kosovo and a Schengen visa._

Comment: Do you already have the visa? If so, please edit your question to include what the visa says in the "valid for" field.

Comment: @QHarr is UNMIK still using travel documents?  If so, getting one would seem to be a fairly simple solution.

Comment: @Aganju the problem is that Schengen visas issued in Kosovar passports are issued with "limited territorial validity" (LTV) so as to exclude Spain.

Comment: I'm new to the site so really only shared what came up as a quick google for something more recent that looked reasonably sound and might be another avenue for investigation. I guess the next stop would be documentation on their website under the applicable process.

Answer (score 3):

Not only do you need a passport accepted by Spain, you also need a visa issued by Spain in Skopje.

A Schengen Visa issued by the the other members **is not valid for Spain**.

Unfortunately, the given link to their Embassy in Skopje does not work at the moment and the Foreign Office page gives no details. The EU page is a bit outdated (2016).

The Spanish consulate site in Hamburg (2018-10-29), states clearly that Kosovo passports are **not** reconized as valid travel document and that only one exception exists for the issuing of a visa.

Assume that you will be **refused entry** if controlled at the border.

If caught inside Spain without valid papers

- will face a heavy punishment

It would seem that Spain does not recognize Kosovo as a state, which would include their passports.

---

[Travel to the EU from Kosovo - European External Action Service](https://eeas.europa.eu/delegations/kosovo_en/1389/Travel%20to%20the%20EU%20from%20Kosovo) (2016-05-12)

> **Where can I travel to with a visa issued by Schengen States?**
>   Short stay visas issued by the following Schengen States in Kosovo passports allow you to travel to all Schengen States **except Spain, Slovakia and Greece**:
>   Austria, Belgium, the Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Latvia, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, the Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Slovenia, Sweden and Switzerland.
>
> The short stay visas issued by Spain, Slovakia and Greece are territorially limited to Spain, Slovakia and Greece respectively.
>
> **Embassy of Spain in Skopje**:
>   Ul, 27 Mart, nº 7, 1000 Skopje, fYROM.
>   Tel: +389 2 3231 002/+389 2 3215 411
>   Fax: +389 2 3220 612
>   Website: [www.maec.es/subwebs/Embajadas/Skopje/](https://www.maec.es/subwebs/Embajadas/Skopje)

The [Spanish Foreign Office Entry Requirements](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Portal/en/ServiciosAlCiudadano/InformacionParaExtranjeros/Paginas/RequisitosDeEntrada.aspx) site gives no details of what of passport is required from Kosovo citizens.

[Spezielle Einreisebestimmungen für kosovarische Staatsangehörige](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/HAMBURGO/de/InfoAus/Paginas/EinreisebestimmungenKosovarenVIEJO.aspx) (2018-10-29, German only)

> **Special entry requirements for Kosovar nationals**
>   As passports issued by the Kosovo authorities are not recognized by Spain, Kosovar nationals are not allowed to enter Spain with their Kosovar passport.
>
> > Exception: Family members of Union citizens.
>
> Kosovo is not recognized by Spain as a state.
>   Therefore, Spain does not recognize Kosovan citizenship and also passports issued by the current Kosovar authorities, so they are not valid in Spain.
>   Kosovar nationals are not allowed to enter Spain with their Kosovar passport as they do not have a travel document recognized by Spain.

Comment: what kind of heavy punishment?

Comment: @flirtymuffin illegal entry, invalid travel documents.

Comment: I mean what exactly? Any fine or just banning you from the county? What did you mean by punishment?

Comment: @flirtymuffin based on reports about illegal immigrants from Africa, detainment and deportation. I would call their Embassy and ask. Their sites give no information/details. The EU information is from 2016 and may be outdated.

Comment: @MarkJohnson By and large, embassies do not give legal advice, especially not to foreignors.

Comment: @MJeffryes a Cousulate will give out in information about a visa/passport requirement.

Comment: And I suspect that asking about the penalties for violating immigration law might be a bad thing to do.

Comment: @DJClayworth That would be a question for law.stackexchange and could only be answered properly by someone who can read Spanish properly (which I can't).

Comment: Yes my point was basically what @DJClayworyh said. I thought your comment was suggesting calling up the embassy and asking “what happens if I illegally enter your country”

Comment: @MJeffryes No, my mind was on the visa/passport problem. I found no reports of what may happen in such a case. One report however claims that Spain's reason for this is that the Kosovo situation is (for them) is to similar to the Catalonia situation.

Comment: Must the visa be issued in Skopje?  We don't know that OP lives in Kosovo.  A Kosovar who lives e.g. in Russia would normally have a visa issued by a Spanish consulate in Russia, no?

Comment: @phoog since the Spanish Consulate in Russia in **not** contained in the quoted EU source, no.

Comment: That source is addressed to residents of Kosovo.  There is nothing there suggesting that a Kosovar who resides in Moscow (or Auckland or Montreal) would have to travel to Macedonia in order to apply for a Schengen visa.

Comment: @phoog that source addresses the fact that Schengen Visa issued by other countries are not valid for Spain and for Spain a direct application is needed. Where the reader does that, is then up to them.